# Is there any way to get refund details (ie. which items have been returned)?

Tags: square-connect

I am working on integration and need to get the refunded items inventory adjusted in our ERP. But I'm not getting any information about what items have actually been returned. I've tried the refunds as well as the payments endpoints.

```
"refunds": [
    {
        "type": "PARTIAL",
        "created_at": "2017-08-03",
        "processed_at": "2017-08-03",
        "reason": "Returned Goods",
        "refunded_money": {
            "amount": -1100,
            "currency_code": "USD"
        },
        "payment_id": "XXXXXXXXX",
        "merchant_id": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
        "refunded_processing_fee_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency_code": "USD"
        }
=====>    ITEM_ID????
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [v1 Payments endpoint](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#navsection-payments)? That should have the itemization information you need for each refund.

Most developers use the inventory endpoints to do full syncs of other inventory management systems however.

Comment: Yes I did. The payment returns an array of [refunds](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#datatype-refund) that has no item information only the moneys.

Comment: That might be the most information that you have available. Most of the time merchants will be refunding dollar amounts, or the whole ticket.

Comment: But really, the inventory endpionts I think are what you should be using for this.